# VBA: A better solution required for downloading multiple files

Tags: excel, selenium, web-scraping, download, vba

I am using a code to download a csv file from a website. At first I tried the traditional approach of creating an `InternetExplorer.Application` and so On.. This was the slowest method . Later I figured out the use Of selenium Wrapper and Created this following code :

```
'Option Explicit

Sub ScripHistoryDownloader()
Flag5 = 0

Dim selDriver As Object
Dim URL As String, Scripcode As String
Dim StartDate As String, EndDate As String
Dim ScripHistPATH As String, DownloadedScripHistFILE As String, ScripHistFILE As String

ScripHistPATH = "R:\DataStore\003__ScripHistory\"

Scripcodez = "500010"

ScripHistFILE = ScripHistPATH & Scripcodez & ".csv"

StartDate = "01/01/1990"
URL = "http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/StockPrcHistori.aspx?expandable=7&scripcode=" & Scripcodez & "&flag=sp&Submit=G"
ChromeDownloadsURL = "chrome://downloads/"


Set selDriver = CreateObject("SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver")
selDriver.Start "chrome", "http://www.google.com/"
selDriver.Open URL

selDriver.Type "id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate", StartDate
selDriver.findElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit").Click
selDriver.Click "id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit"
selDriver.clickAndWait "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDownload"
selDriver.Open ChromeDownloadsURL

'Checking if download is Completed.
downloadChecker:
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    DownloadedSHFileName = selDriver.findElementByClassName("name").Text
    If DownloadedSHFileName = "" Then
    GoTo downloadChecker
    End If

'Finding out where the file is downloaded and moving it to the desired location.
ChromeDownloadsHtml = selDriver.getHtmlSource
PathStartPosition = InStr(ChromeDownloadsHtml, "file:///")
PathStartPosition = PathStartPosition + 8
TempPathText = Mid(ChromeDownloadsHtml, PathStartPosition)
PathEndPosition = InStr(TempPathText, "/" & Scripcodez)
ScrambledPath = Left(TempPathText, PathEndPosition)
DownloadedScripHistFILE = Replace(ScrambledPath, "/", "\") & DownloadedSHFileName
selDriver.stop
MoveOrRenameFile DownloadedScripHistFILE, ScripHistFILE

Set selDriver = Nothing

Flag5 = 1
EndOfBhavCopyDownloader:
End Sub


'Function to Move or rename a file or Folder
Sub MoveOrRenameFile(SourcePath As String, DestinationPath As String)
    Name SourcePath As DestinationPath
End Sub
```

The code runs totally OK. I use this code to download about 3000 files daily and is triggered whenever my computer is ON. My problem is that whenever this code is triggered the chrome browser pops up and also a cmd window.I dont want this popups to happen when using chrome. There is no way to hide the browser and the cmd window like we hide IE using `ie.Visible = False` in the `InternetExplorer.Application`. Also opening browser, navigating... makes the process very slow.
**Is it possible to perform the above code operations using `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` object ?** I have used(with assistance of examples) `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` object but I haven't filled forms on a website to generate a file and then download it.(I don't have much knowledge about using it)... Can anyone show me a way? Any help is appreciated.

Note: The posted code is on of the modules from my project: 
[My Entire Project for reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwoM8DdKUllZVFIxVFN3RWptMjg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Tim Williams Thanks..i dont think its possible to edit the webpage form using that method.. or may be I didn't understand it correctly.. testing it...

Comment: no its not possible ... the file is generated by a function i guess... there's no Direct URL to the file present on the page [Webpage](http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/StockPrcHistori.aspx?expandable=7&scripcode=" & Scripcodez & "&flag=sp&Submit=G), searched using Inspect element option of chrome.

Comment: Sorry - too hasty reading the question: I think you're stuck with your current approach or something similar.

Comment: yup .. i wanted my project to run in background once it was finished... but this current approach won't let me do that with all the pop ups, so looking for an alternative...